# run a set of queries faster with python and postgres

Tags: python, postgresql

in my example, I have a list of 3000 words to search in a database, so with this pyhton code (I am using django) the operation takes a lot of time and is done in 3.5 minutes with the average of 120ms for a querie.  is there a method to speed up the execution of these queries with a script python using threads or something like that?

```
 def my_custom_sql(ent):
    for e in ent:
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            entity=e.replace("'","''")
         
            cursor.execute("SELECT object FROM yagofacts WHERE subject='{}' AND object LIKE '<wordnet_%>';".format(entity))
         
            row = cursor.fetchall()
            print(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify your method like the code shown below. It will use the same cursor to fire all the queries and hence will be faster.

```
with connection.cursor() as cursor:    
    for e in ent:
        entity=e.replace("'","''")
        cursor.execute("SELECT object FROM yagofacts WHERE subject='{}' AND object LIKE '<wordnet_%>';".format(entity)) 
        row = cursor.fetchall()
        print(row)
```

If this is not helping, then try connection pooling. It may help in your case.

Comment: Thank u for your response. it decreases but just a little. because there I am going to do 2000 select .. there is no way to search in a this huge database faster.!! . I have already created the indexes as well for the databases.

Comment: I have commented on the answer  about connection pools. Please search for them.